# XPath: как получить содержимое только тех узлов, которые находятся внутри родителей с нужным названием?

Tags: php, html, xml, запрос, xpath

Разбираю html с такой структурой:

```
<div class="versions">
    <div class="meld" data-versions-items="2021 г.">
         <a href="https://www.englishforcing.ru/novosti/po-anglijski-v-budushhem-budut-govorit-s- 
         indijskim-akcentom-britanskij-lingvist/"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="meld" data-versions-items="2020 г.">
         <a href="https://www.englishforcing.ru/novosti/po-anglijski-v-budushhem-budut-govorit-s- 
         indijskim-akcentom-britanskij-lingvist/"></a>
    </div>
        <div class="meld" data-versions-items="2019 г.">
      <a href="https://www.englishforcing.ru/novosti/po-anglijski-v-budushhem-budut-govorit-s-indijskim-akcentom-britanskij-lingvist/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Хочу с помощью XPath забрать одним запросом все ссылки за 2020, 2019 года, а за 2021, допустим, не брать.. Как мне получить ссылки из всех узлов за нужные года...? Пробовал так:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($html);
    
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$elements = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"versions")]');
```

и так:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
        $document->loadHTML($html);
        
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$experiments = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@data-versions-items,"2020 г.")]');
```

За 2020 год дает информацию, но мне хотелось бы за несколько лет и обойтись без подстановки нескольких возможных вариантов в цикле, потому что тогда будет несколько xpath зарпосов, а это избыточно..

Можно ли добиться нужного результата и как? Я уже не знаю, что попробовать..

Comment: `'//div[contains(@data-versions-items,"2020 г.")|contains(@data-versions-items,"2019 г.")]/a'` как-нибудь так можно попробовать. А если бы можно было хранить в изначальной структуре год без " г." то по идее и знаками `<` и `>` можно задавать интервал

Comment: Какая у вас версия XPath?

Comment: Тоже не работает, выдает такие ошибки: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid type in W:\lk\sd\script.php on line 56

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in W:\lk\sd\script.php on line 62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для XPath 2.0 и новее.

Основано на идее последовательностей (sequences).

**XPath 2.0 или новее**

```
/div/div[substring(@data-versions-items,1,4)=("2019","2020")]
```

**XPath 1.0**

```
/div/div[substring(@data-versions-items,1,4)="2019" or substring(@data-versions-items,1,4)="2020"]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version 2.9.9
HTML Support enabled
XPath Support enabled

Comment: Но код не работает почему-то..выдает такую ошибку: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in W:\lk\sd\script.php on line 56

Comment: версия XPAth - 2.9.9

Comment: Речь шла о соответствии стандарту XPath: 1.0, 2.0 или 3.0 / 3.1

Comment: @Valentin, Я обновил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо! Сейчас попробую..

Comment: Тоже не срабатывает, пустоту отдает..

Comment: @Valentin, Я добавил снимок экрана, чтобы показать, что это работает.

Comment: @Valentin, Очень возможно, что ваш настоящий XML отличается от того, что вы показали. Можете попробовать поставить две косые черты  `//div/...` в начале XPath.

Comment: Да, действительно, отличается, просто не могу реальный вариант опубликовать. Да, сейчас попробую..

Comment: Да, с 2 слешами работает, спасибо!